# Is there a library or support in Unity to do Firebase activities in Windows?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

Recently I saw the documentation of using Firebase in Unity (It's still in beta or experimental, the documentation) and it says that as requirement I need xCode (Mac OS) so this documentation is for Mac, but I wonder if there is a library or Firebase SDK for Unity in Windows.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

at the moment iOS and Android are the only platforms officially supported by the Firebase Unity SDK

https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

but one can use Firebase Realtime Database in the Windows Unity Editor

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start

if only we could use Authentication as well...
i can't be the only dev who'd love a multi-platform social login solution

especially one that doesn't require extra SDKs for each login provider,
and i just use Application.OpenURL to magically get a providers access_token somehow